# The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic')

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

When I log in into wcf **localhost/Service1.svc** I get Error:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not
>   allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding'
>   ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to
>   Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be
>   resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application
>   through the IIS management tool, through the
>   ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the
>   application configuration file at the 
>   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
>   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule"
        type="WCF_Customer_RentalObject.BasicAuthHttpModule, WCF_Customer_RentalObject"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Do you know what I have to do?**

When I add this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding> <!--Notice, no name attribute set-->
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I get another error:

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding'
>   ('Negotiate').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to
>   Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be
>   resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application
>   through the IIS management tool, through the
>   ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the
>   application configuration file at the 
>   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
>   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.

Comment: Yes I read but I don`t know how change this in web.config

Comment: did you google? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Suggested client config:**

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicEndpoint">
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"
                   proxyCredentialType="None"
                   realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

May be `mode="TransportCredentialOnly">` is OK
but `<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />`
is probably not the best

**2. Pass the credentials :**

```C#
HelloServiceClient client = new HelloServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
String msg = client.SayHello(userName);
```

Hope it helps